# How to display image in wxpython?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, pycharm

Please help me with this code. I want to display image in the frame :

```
import wx
import os

class frame(wx.Frame):
    '''frame class that display an image'''
    def __init__(self, image, parent=None, id=-1,
            pos=wx.DefaultPosition, title='Hello, wxPyhton!'):
        '''creat a frame instance and display image.'''
        temp = image.ConvertToBitmap()
        size = temp.GetWidth(), temp.GetHeight()
        wx.Frame(parent, id, pos, title, size)
        self.bmp = wx.StaticBitmap(parent=self, bitmap=temp)
class App(wx.App):
    '''Application class.'''

    def OnInit(self):
        image = wx.Image('clem.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG)
        self.frame = frame(image)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()
```

But i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/PycharmProjects/WXPYHTON/hello.py", line 18, in OnInit
 self.frame = frame(image)
 File "C:/PycharmProjects/WXPYHTON/hello.py", line 11, in __init__
 wx.Frame(parent, id, pos, title, size)
TypeError: Frame(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
overload 1: too many arguments
overload 2: argument 3 has unexpected type 'Point'
OnInit returned false, exiting...
Process finished with exit code 1
```

please help this code. i don't know where i'm getting it wrong.

I've changed it but i'm still getting this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/PycharmProjects/WXPYHTON/hello.py", line 18, in OnInit
self.frame = frame(image)
File "C:/PycharmProjects/WXPYHTON/hello.py", line 12, in __init__
self.bmp = wx.StaticBitmap(parent=None, bitmap=temp)
TypeError: StaticBitmap(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
overload 1: 'parent' is not a valid keyword argument
overload 2: 'bitmap' is not a valid keyword argument
OnInit returned false, exiting...
```

**please check my self.bmp, if it is correct. Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initialising the frame properly and you are using keywords as variable names.
Change:

```
wx.Frame(parent, id, pos, title, size)
```

To:

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,pos=pos,title=title,size=size)
```

and it should work.

Comment: your original code read `self.bmp = wx.StaticBitmap(parent=self, bitmap=temp)` now the error reads `self.bmp = wx.StaticBitmap(parent=None, bitmap=temp)`  A bitmap should have a parent window not `None`. Go back to using `parent=self`. Those errors look like they are coming from pycharm, of which I know nothing.